# NoSuchElementException selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation

So I am trying to automate to preorder the ps5 but the issue is the preorder button vanishes if its out of stock. this code is throwing NoSuchElementException. I am trying to refresh the page until the button appears

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(someWebsite)
buttonPresent = False

while not buttonPresent:
    if driver.find_element_by_id("buy-now-button") == selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()

    else:
        driver.find_element_by_id("buy-now-button").click()
        buttonPresent = True
```

Comment: You have to wait for particular element.

Comment: Yes I understand that's what I am trying to achieve(if element not present it refreshes page until it appears) but this code crashes with exception. Do you recommend something to improve it?

Comment: can you share URL of site to me for checking?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B08FV5GC28/ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_button_2a1_w?pf_rd_m=A1K21FY43GMZF8&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-1&pf_rd_r=D97962AHNQ5MEXM7TN56&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=51eb9107-6050-4cf4-9331-18894cfaff97&pf_rd_i=21725163031